# sas, remove the comma and period, regex

Tags: regex, sas

Do you guys know how to replace remove the comma and period in something like this:

```
'18430109646000104331929350001,064380958490001,974317618110001,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,. '
```

I had to concatenate to get list of claim numbers (with leading zeros). Now, I have that string but I want to delete all the stuff at the end. I tried  this but it didn't work

```
data OUT.REQ_1_4_25 ;
   set OUT.REQ_1_4_24;
   CONCAT1=PRXCHANGE('s/,.//',1,CONCAT);
run;
```

By the way, I am using SAS and regex, something like prxchange.

Comment: I think the question you should ask is how to create the "thing" you show in the code box.  Did you use || concatenation operator or CATX function.  probably just need CATX and OPTIONS MISSING=' ';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument to the PRXCHANGE function specifies the number of times the search and replace should be done. Replacing your 1 by -1 will run the replacement until the end of the string, rather than only once.

Also, the pair ',.' will replace a comma followed by any character ('.' is a wildcard). You want to catch either a comma (',') or a period ('.'), the last of which is a metacharacter you need to escape from, using '\':

```
CONCAT1=PRXCHANGE('s/[,\.]//',-1,CONCAT);
```

If you only want to remove the comma-period pairs, then remove the square brackets:

```
CONCAT1=PRXCHANGE('s/,\.//',-1,CONCAT);
```

Answer (score 1):

This also worked for me

```
    data OUT.REQ_1_4_25 ;
   set OUT.REQ_1_4_24;
   CONCAT1=TRANWRD(CONCAT, ',.', ''); 

run;
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for regex unless you have something more complicated than actually shown.

Just use the `scan()` function and tell it to use `.` and `,` as delimiters:

```
data claims;
  length claim $50;
  list = '18430109646000104331929350001,064380958490001,974317618110001,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.';
  cnt=1;
  claim=scan(list,cnt,'.,');
  do while (claim ne '');
    output;
    cnt=cnt+1;
    claim=scan(list,cnt,'.,');
  end;
  keep claim;
run;
```